# How I can get formated string from List array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, spring

Sorry, I'm beginner in Java. I work with Spring and Hibernate and I have problem. In Internet I can't find solution.

My Controller:

```
List<User> theModerators = userDAO.findAllModerators();

theModel.addAttribute("moderators", theModerators); return "moderators";
```

moderators.jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${moderators}" var="m">
     <div>${m.firstName}</div>
     <c:forEach items="${m.companies}" var="company">
         <div>${company.compName}</div>
     </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

I have problem with with company.compName. I want to get formated string with commas (ex: I got "MicrosoftApple", but I want - "Microsoft, Apple").

I know about join, for ex:

```
String allCompanies = String.join(", ", userCompanies);
```

But I can't add allCompanies string  to theModerators, or create new array like theModerators but with allCompanies string.

I have worked with PHP/Laravel, and there I used joins into collections.

But in Java I can't do it.

Comment: have you tried <div>${company.compName},</div>

Comment: Yes, I got "MicrosoftApple"

Comment: Bring the formatted string from your controller method.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't understand how I can formatted string bring back to theModerators list. theModerators.forEach(moderator->{ String moderatorCompanies = String.join(", ", moderator.getCompanies()); // So I have the moderatorCompanies string. How I can put it back, for ex: moderator.companies = moderatorCompanies; // this don't work.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
<c:forEach items="${moderators}" var="m">
     <div>${m.firstName}</div>
      <div>
     <c:forEach items="${m.companies}" var="company" varStatus="item">
         ${company.compName}
         <c:if test="${!item.last}">,</c:if>
     </c:forEach>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I have made use of [varStatus](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) to avoid the last comma

Comment: But I get comma  always: John - Microsoft, | Alex - Microsoft, Apple,

Comment: Do u mean to say that you want to avoid printing last comma?

Comment: Actually, `<c:if test="${!item.last}">,</c:if>` is there to avoid the same problem. Can u perhaps try using  `<c:if test="${not item.last}">,</c:if>`?

Comment: It works like the first - printing last comma too :(

Comment: I don't think so. This has worked for me earlier.Will try to set some example later in the day.. In the meanwhile, can you try printing `<c:out value="${item.last}">`? For JSTL `c:forEach varStatus` has a property `last isLast()` which is a Flag indicating whether the current round is the last pass through the iteration. You can also try searching for `varStatus` in jstl.